# SyntaxError: invalid regexp group in firefox. But work in chrome

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the meaning of the below regex. Can any one explain it?

```
var str1 = "sample1";
var str2 = "sample2";
str1.search(new RegExp("(?<=(\\s|^|,))("+str2+")(?=(\\s|,|$))", "gi")) === -1)
```

The above regex not work in firefox. SyntaxError: invalid regexp group. But work in chrome.

Comment: Use `new RegExp("(?:^|[\\s,])(" + str2 + ")(?![^\\s,])", "i").test(str1)`, a non-capturing group is more than enough if you need to `test` a string for a regex match. There is no need to use a global modifier if you do this.

Comment: You have a syntax error by the way.  ```str1.search(new RegExp("(?<=(\\s|^|,))("+str2+")(?=(\\s|,|$))", "gi") === -1)```  There was an additional parenthesis after `..."gi")̀`